# What is the asymtotic complexity of the following code

Tags: complexity-theory

I have some doubts about the complexity of the following code
The outer loop is going to execute for O(N) times
I have doubts about the inner loop whether it is going to execute for O(1) or O(n)

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
for (int j=i; j< i; j+=i) 
{ 
print(“*”);
}
}
```

Comment: I think this would be O(n * log n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone pointed out, as the code stands the inner loop will execute 0 times, so I'm assuming you meant:

```c
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  for (int j=0; j<n; j+=i) 
  { 
    print(“*”);
  }
}
```

In that case, the number of executions of the inner loop will be `N, N/2, N/3, N/4, ...` in the subsequent executions of the outer loop. So the total time will be `N + N/2 + N/3 + ... = N * (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ...)`. Now, we can see that `(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ...) <= (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 + ...)`. This second expression requires twice as many terms for each additional `1/2` (for example you need twice as many `1/8` as `1/4` to make a `1/2`) so it will be `O(logN)`. So the total complexity is `O(N*logN)`.

Answer (score 0):

The inner is O(i), which increases everytime, so the global complexity would be:
Number of times the inner loop is executed: 1+2+3+...+n, that is:

[image: summatory]

Therefore O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Because j is initialized to i in the inner loop, that loop never executes as the condition requires j be less than i. Therefore, the complexity is O(n): all this does is increment i in the outer loop and verify during each iteration of the outer loop body that i is not less than i.